# Implementing some variation of Bron–Kerbosch algorithm in python

Tags: python

for a college project I'm trying to implement [that algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sM9LC.jpg), but my code doesn't print all the answers after testing. For example for `graph = [[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]]` he show's:

```
Clique found: [1, 4]
Clique found: [1, 5]
Clique found: [1, 6]
Clique found: [2, 4]
Clique found: [2, 5]
Clique found: [2, 6]
Clique found: [4, 3]
Clique found: [6, 3]
```

but correct answer is (he forgot about [3,5]):

```
[1, 4]
[1, 5]
[1, 6]
[2, 4]
[2, 5]
[2, 6]
[3, 4]
[3, 5]
[3, 6]
```

my code so far is :

```py
def Clique(N, D, Z):
    if not any((N, D)):
        file_S = []
        for i in range(len(S)):
            file_S.append(S[i] + 1)
        print('Clique found: ' + str(file_S))
    elif N:
        for x in N:
            View(N, D, x)
            if Z is not None and x in Z:
                Z.remove(x)
            Z_adj = Adj(x, graph)
            for i in range(len(Z_adj)):
                if Z is not None and Z_adj[i] in Z:
                    Z.remove(Z_adj[i])
            while Z:
                v = Z[0]
                View(N, D, v)
                if v in Z:
                    Z = Z.remove(v)

def View(N, D, v):
    if v in N:
        N.remove(v)
    S.append(v)
    N_v = Adj(v, graph)
    D_v = Adj(v, graph)
    N_adj = list(set(N) & set(N_v))
    D_adj = list(set(D) & set(D_v))
    Clique(N_adj, D_adj, N_adj)
    S.remove(v)
    D.append(v)

def Adj(v, X):
    return [i for i, n_v in enumerate(X[v]) if n_v]

graph = [[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]]


X = []
for i in range(len(graph)):
    X.append(i)
S = []
N = X.copy()
D = []
Z = X.copy()
Clique(N, D, Z)
```

Any help why I'm getting only a part of the answer ?

Comment: I'm not a great fan of this side-effect based style it makes it very hard to follow. One thing that is likely to cause issues is that you are iterating over `N` - `for x in N` and then modifying that same list in `View()` - `if v in N: N.remove(v)`. This will lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: @AChampion thanks i'm fixed case iterating `N` - `for x in N[:]:` what about second issue? I dont understand how to fix that